# robocopy to Drive File Stream Fails in powershell but not at command line Error 5

Tags: powershell, google-drive, robocopy

When I run the robocopy at an admin command prompt it runs successfully.

> C:\Users\StoreMgr>robocopy
>   "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks Point of Sale
>   12.0\Data\Paracept" "G:\My Drive\Backup" qbpos1.db
>
> ROBOCOPY :: Robust File Copy for Windows Started : Friday, April 6,
>   2018 3:46:37 PM Source : C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks
>   Point of Sale 12.0\Data\Paracept\ Dest = G:\My Drive\Backup\
>
> Files : qbpos1.db Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
>
> ```
>                    1    C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks Point of Sale
> ```
>
> 12.0\Data\Paracept\ 100% Newer 215.1 m qbpos1.db
>
> ```
>        Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
> ```
>
> Files : 1 1 0 0 0 0 Bytes : 215.13 m 215.13 m 0 0 0 0 Times : 0:00:01
>   0:00:01 0:00:00 0:00:00
>
> Speed : 164779476 Bytes/sec. Speed : 9428.757 MegaBytes/min. Ended :
>   Friday, April 6, 2018 3:46:38 PM

When I run it in powershell I get an error:

```
ROBOCOPY :: Robust File Copy for Windows
Started : Friday, April 6, 2018 4:47:58 PM 2018/04/06 16:47:58 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination G:\My Drive\QBBackups\ Access is denied.

Source : C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks Point of Sale 12.0\Data\Paracept\ Dest - G:\My Drive\QBBackups\

Files : qbpos1.db
Options : /V /DCOPY:D /COPY:DT /B /R:1000000 /W:30

2018/04/06 16:47:58 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory G:\My Drive\QBBackups\ Access is denied.

Bat file: powershell.exe -executionpolicy Bypass .\QBScheduledBackup.ps1 -GDrivePath 'G:\My Drive\QBBackups' -Version 12.0 -CompanyName Paracept

robocopy Command: Robocopy $DBSPath $GDrivePath qbpos1.db /COPY:DT /B /V /LOG:"C:\RobocopyLog1.txt"
```

I have run it without parameters in powershell with the same errors

Running powershell as admin in all cases

Robocopy  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks Point of Sale 12.0\Data\Paracept   G:\My Drive\Paracept  qbpos1.db

Comment: What is the actual Robocopy command that you run in powershell?

Comment: robocopy Command: Robocopy $DBSPath $GDrivePath qbpos1.db /COPY:DT /B /V /LOG:"C:\RobocopyLog1.txt"

Comment: Is that in a script?

Comment: Yes Powershell run as administrator

Comment: Then that is not the actual command that is being run. It is the un-intertoplated line of code in your script. It sounds like we need to see your code or at the very least an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: PS D:\Documents\Starbuds\StarbudsInstallFolder\Backup And Security\QB BacKup>

Comment: Robocopy  C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks Point of Sale 12.0\Data\Starbuds   G:\My Drive\Starbuds  qbpos1.db

Comment: Robocopy  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks Point of Sale 12.0\Data\Starbuds"   "G:\My Drive\Starbuds"  qbpos1.db

Comment: Please update your question with the actual code you are running or an MCV.

Comment: The cmd window uses a destination path of `G:\My Drive\Backup` the ps window shows a different destination of `G:\My Drive\QBBackups` Does one of these backup directories exist before the command is run? Does the account running the command have the ability to create data at `G:\My Drive` if one of the backup dirs does *not* exist?

Comment: Both Paths exist

Comment: They both exist